# Why is d-separation only for disjoint sets?

Tags: causality, causal-diagram, d-separation, backdoor-path

I'm reading Molak's [*Causal Inference and Discovery in Python: Unlock the secrets of modern causal machine learning with DoWhy, EconML, PyTorch and more*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1804612987) and I made note that I've taken the disjointedness of sets in d-separation for granted.

That is, for a DAG $G = (V, E(V))$, if I wish to consider whether the sets of vertices $\mathscr{X}$ and $\mathscr{Y}$ are d-separated by $\mathscr{Z}$ they should be disjoint as a requirement.

Is this disjointedness requirement in the definition just to avoid uninteresting cases, or is there a potential logic problem (undefined cases and/or contradictions)?

---

I've also [started a discussion](https://github.com/networkx/networkx/discussions/6889) on networkx about the fact that their `nx.d_separated` checker seems to have defined behavior in non-disjoint cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Definitions

Let us recall the definition of d-separation (Pearl, 2009, definition 1.2.3, p. 16-17):

> A path $p$ is said to be *d-separated* (or *blocked*) by a set of nodes $Z$ if and only if

> 1. $p$ contains a chain $i \rightarrow m \rightarrow j$ or a fork $i \leftarrow m \rightarrow j$ such that the middle node $m$ is in $Z$, or
> 2. $p$ contains an inverted fork (or *collider*) $i \rightarrow m \leftarrow j$ such that the middle node $m$ is not in $Z$ and such that no descendant of $m$ is in $Z$

In more intuitive terms, two variables are *d*-separated if they are not *d*-connected (ibid, p. 336):

> $x$ and $y$ are *d*-connected, condition on a set $Z$ of nodes, if there is a collider-free path between $x$ and $y$ that traverses no member of $Z$. If no such path exists, we say that $x$ and $y$ are *d*-separated by $Z$.

### Example

Consider:

- The (almost) most simple causal DAG $X \longrightarrow Y$.
- The most simple pair of non-disjoint sets $\mathcal{X} = \{X\}$ and $\mathcal{Y} = \{X\}$, i.e. two sets with the same variable $X$.
- The most simple adjustment set, the empty set, $Z = \{\emptyset\}$.

We can see, by the definitions above, that $X$ is *d*-separated from
$X$—there is no path to begin with, much less an open path.

In a causal DAG under the causal Markov assumption, d-separation **implies** conditional independence. That is, we expect $\mathcal{X} \mathrel{\unicode{x2AEB}} \mathcal{Y} | Z = X \mathrel{\unicode{x2AEB}} X | \emptyset = X \mathrel{\unicode{x2AEB}} X$, i.e. that $X$ is independent of itself. In turn, this means that we expect

$F(x, x) = F(x) F(x)$, for all $x$,

where $F$ is the cumulative distribution function of $X$. This would only be true if $F(x)$ is equal to $1$ or $0$ for all $x$, i.e. if $X$ is constant. We did not assume that $X$ was a constant, hence we see that working with non-disjoint sets is problematic.

You might think that it is an absurd example to choose the same variable twice, but note that (ibid, p. 335):

> "the extension [of d-separation] to sets of variables is straightforward (i.e., two sets are separated if and only if each element in one set is separated from every element in the other)"

Thus, with non-disjoint sets you will **always** be checking for d-separation of a variable with itself.

### Conclusion

If you do not change any other definitions, working with non-disjoint sets will break many established theorems in the field (such as the implication of conditional independence from d-separation), unless you work with very niche special cases with constant variables.

Comment: Observation prompted by the answer (+1): So the set of all paths (ignoring edge direction) between a node and itself would be the set of all cycles that it participates in.

Comment: I think a trivial digraph (i.e. single node and no edges) would technically be a DAG, and in some sense of counting nodes and edges would be simpler than $X \rightarrow Y$. But it would be of no interest from the perspective of making a  causal inference.

Comment: @Galen yes, you are right a single node would be the most simple causal DAG in that case